# launcher icon resizing

Tags: android, icons, size, launcher

I am trying to make my MediaShortcut app ([source](http://code.google.com/p/image-shortcut))
create launcher icons whose size depends on the density of the screen. 
The image is retreived from [android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html).getThumbnail(getContentResolver(), "imageid"), android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null)

So first i get the screen's density using 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html
and then resize the image according to this table http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html

This seems to work fine on most of my devices but on my Asus slider 
(and a friends transformer) the icon is significantly smaller than the 
other icons on the home screen. on other devices i have noticed the icon is too big and only part of it is shown.

Does anybody have any idea why this could be? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to make the launcher icon with Android Asset Studio? http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html
This should resize the image to all required sizes. Then make sure you put them in the correct drawable folders in res.

Comment: no i get the icons from a content provider. it is (incorrectly) resized and set as the result of android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT

Answer (score 0):

since api 11 the launcher icon size is implementation specific.
i home homescreen apps honor this...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getLauncherLargeIconDensity()
and
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getLauncherLargeIconSize()